# Making it Pythonic: create a sqlite3 database if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python, sqlite

I wrote a Python script which initializes an empty database if it doesn't exist.

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('Database'):
    os.makedirs('Database')
    os.system('sqlite3 Database/testDB.db ";"')

# rest of the script...
```

Can I do this in a more Pythonic fashion, with a try-except, or is this kind of code acceptable?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database/testDB.db')
```

This should connect to your database and create it in case that it doesn't exist. I'm not sure this is the most pythonic way, but it does use the `sqlite3` module instead of the `sqlite3` command.

Comment: Note that sqlite3.connect create the db file only as long as the parent directory exists.

Comment: Note that `sqlite3.connect()`'s path argument cannot be used with relative path like `~`,use it with absolute path works in my case.

Answer (score 7):

> ## Making it Pythonic: create a sqlite3 database if it doesn't exist?

The most *Pythonic* way to do this is to use the context manager:

```
import sqlite3

# if we error, we rollback automatically, else commit!
with sqlite3.connect('/Temp/testDB.db') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print('SQLite version:', data)
```

In a python shell this echoes for me:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0CCAD4D0>
SQLite version: (u'3.5.9',)
```

To ensure you have a tempfile path that works across platforms, use `tempfile.gettempdir`:

```
import tempfile
with sqlite3.connect(tempfile.gettempdir() + '/testDB.db') as conn:
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

## Create directory path, database file and table

Here is a recipe to create the directory path, database file and table
when necessary. If these already exist, the script will overwrite nothing and simply use what is at hand.

```
import os
import sqlite3

data_path = './really/deep/data/path/'
filename = 'whatever'

os.makedirs(data_path, exist_ok=True)

db = sqlite3.connect(data_path + filename + '.sqlite3')
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableName (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, quantity INTEGER)')
db.close()
```

Comment: Perfect - sqlite3.connect create the db file only as long as the parent directory exists.

Answer (score 4):

`sqlite3.connect` will attempt to create a database if it doesn't exist - so the only way to tell if one does exist is to try to open it and catch an `IOError`. Then to create a blank database, just connect using the `sqlite3` module.

```
import sqlite3

try:
    open('idonotexist')
    print 'Database already exists!'
except IOError as e:
    if e.args == 2: # No such file or directory
        blank_db = sqlite3.connect('idontexist')
        print 'Blank database created'
    else: # permission denied or something else?
        print e
```

Of course, you may still have to do something with `os.makedirs` depending on if the structure already exists.